# Generate random number Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
module Meth where
import System.Random



gen :: StdGen
gen = mkStdGen 42

shuffles:: StdGen->[(Int,Int)]
shuffles g = take 28(randoms g :: [Int])
```

I am trying to generate 28 random numbers I keep getting an error
error

> Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘(Int, Int)’
>      Expected type: [(Int, Int)]
>        Actual type: [Int]
>      In the expression: take 28 $ randoms g :: [Int]
>      In an equation for ‘shuffles’:
>          shuffles g = take 28 $ randoms g :: [Int]

Comment: Unmatched parentheses on the last line. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: `take 28 $ randoms g :: [Int]`

Comment: You're generating a list of `Int` and trying to return a list of `(Int, Int)`.

Comment: I put the parentheses but it still giving me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly say you are generating a list of `Int` types:

```
... (randoms g :: [Int])
```

Then you also say you actually want a list of pairs of `Int`s:

```
... -> [ (Int, Int) ]
```

Which do you want?  If you want pairs then split your generator and zip up two separate calls to `randoms`:

```
shuffles:: StdGen->[(Int,Int)]
shuffles g =
    let (g1,g2) = split g
    in take 28 $ zip (randoms g1) (randoms g2)
```

If you just want a list of `Int`s then fix the incorrect type signature:

```
shuffles:: StdGen -> [Int]
shuffles g = take 28 (randoms g)
```